# Wiped out an Efi system hard-disk and now it's not booting

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, efi

I am used to legacy BIOS boot systems, when I switched from windows to linux in such a kind I wiped out the whole hard disk and manually partitioned and installed linux on it. On the new pc which I didn't know was a efi kind or even know such a one existed I wiped out the whole thing again, then I was caught up with some work and I thought I'll leave mint to install (ie) Erase disk and install option thinking that I will move around things later, but the **installer crashed** I don't know why and hence I left without installing the OS to do it manually later, now that I again try to switch on nothing works, I mean I am not even able to get to BIOS or boot loader stage where it should display or boot the OS in my pendrive. When I later read about the differences I understood that link to boot firmware is kept in the hard-disk for faster boot or something. So wiping out the disk, means I can't get my system to boot again? I did find a [similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/764799/how-to-create-an-efi-system-partition) but he's able to get it to boot, mine is not.How to install linux now? Is there a way around. (I am only going to use linux no plan of switching back to windows)

**TL;DR:**  Now I have fresh(fully wiped out) hard disk which was efi based, how to install linux?

Comment: A failed installation *should not* have left the computer in a completely unbootable state (meaning you can't boot an external medium or access the firmware setup utility). That said, many EFIs, particularly from a few years ago, were bug-laden and so might misbehave like that. Unplugging the hard disk should at least enable you to enter the firmware setup utility. Removing all partitions from the disk (using another computer to do so) should do the same. If this doesn't work, then chances are your computer has died -- probably coincidentally.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: you could boot and reinstall linux but to answer your question:

1. boot from cd/dvd
2. say "install "
3. do your settings but use LVM to partition and let linux partition your disk... this will always be good
4. reboot but keep pressing "R"
5. go to  recovery or  advanced (if there is no option for recovery do advanced!)
6. if you are in advanced go to recovery then:
7. if you have chosen repair or advanced>repair choose GRUB
8. update grub

PS: if you are confused from the "R" pressing point or further you can always search for "how do i do a grub-update from boot?"

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response! I get the points that you've listed out, but when I power on my laptop, it doesn't go beyond the Lenovo Thinkpad start screen (I use a Lenovo E420 model laptop). I'm unable to access the boot loader or anything. It is simply stuck there. Could you suggest any ideas on how could I proceed further.

Comment: Or does it mean that my current problem has nothing to do with wiping out the harddisk?

Comment: You can try pressing "F2" or "F12" on boot (i dont know which key for lenovo) just search for LENOVO BIOS KEY and turn off secure boot and set the bios to legacy and boot from CD /DVD

Comment: @PbVignesh Did my previous comment help you?